# Best practices permissions for /etc/pam.d/sshd

Tags: sshd, pam, yubikey

What are the best recommendations for file permissions for `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?

I currently have `0644/-rw-r--r-- root:root` and was wondering if it's a good ideea to go to `600`.
Disclaimer: I use yubikeys as 2FA for ssh, so my PAM contains:

```
auth           required          pam_yubico.so id=XXX key=YYY
```

Yubikey recommends the key be secret, so the file should only be readable by root.
On the other hand, I don't expect the 2FA to be easily bypassed even with the key compromised, since an attacker would need physical access to the Yubikey.

Would `600` still work?

Comment: There's no point in that but if you insist you can do that and try `ssh localhost` and see if it works.

Comment: You also only need to modify the last `r`, since the user and group are both `root:root`.. it's the `other` you should be concerned about